# How to persist Image in DB Using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, file-upload

How to persist Image in Database Using Spring MVC3

controller:

```
public String postAdd(@ModelAttribute("employeeAttribute") @Valid Employee  employee,   BindingResult result,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile   file) throws Exception{

       byte[] bFile=null;

       System.out.println("File Name......"+file.getName());

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {

          bFile = new byte[(int) file.getSize()];
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getOriginalFilename());         
             fileInputStream.read(bFile);
             fileInputStream.close();
            }


              employee.setImage(bFile);

     employeeServiceImpl.add(employee);
```

}

Jsp Page:

```
     <c:url var="saveEmp" value="/manam/mobee/employee/add"/>
       <form:form modelAttribute="employeeAttribute" method="POST" action="${saveEmp}"          enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <form:label path="image">Image</form:label>
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></input>
```

here Iam sending the C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert Landscape.jpg file but 
  FileInputStream it will take only Landscape.jpg .
   please suggest how to set full file path for FileInputStream.

Here I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: Forest.jpg (The system cannot find the file specified) Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original file name is the name of the file on the end-user's machine. Your Spring MVC application runs on your server machine. You can't use the original file name, hope to find the absolute file name on the end-user machine, and even less try to read the file using this name.

To get the contents of the uploaded file, use [`MultipartFile.getBytes()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getBytes%28%29) or [`MultipartFile.getInputStream()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getInputStream%28%29).

Comment: thanx JB Nizet ,here I am passing byte Array to entity but it not saved to db I am getting exception

Comment: That's a completely different problem. Try solving it yourself, and if you can't, ask another question, with the code used to save the byte array, and the stack trace of the exception. And don't forget to upvote and accept answers (this one and previous ones) if they solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take bytes from MultipartFile:

```
 bFile = file.getBytes();
 employee.setImage(bFile);
```

Comment: Still not working vacuum org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [insert into Employee (emailId, empID, empName, image, phoneNo, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [72000]; error code [1461]; Could not execute JDBC batch update; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: Could not execute JDBC batch update] with root cause
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Comment: check your database mapping. Looks like, you dont have proper column type for image field